# upgrading to ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, 16.04, 15.10

Hello every one I want to upgrade my ubuntu os from 15.10 to 16.04 but the thing is that when it just starts upgrading it shows this massage 'apt (>= 1.0.10.2ubuntu2)` what the problem is can you help me?

Comment: Please show the entire error message...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
exec sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
apt-get -m install
apt-get install --reinstall apt
do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: thanks for your helping but it doesn,t work.!!!

Answer (score 0):

apt version 1.0.10.2ubuntu2 is part of regular Wily.
I assume you didn't update your distribution for some time.

Make sure that you have valid Wily repository in the /etc/apt/sources.list and do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before you try to upgrade to a newer version.

This should install the required apt version.

Should your repo not work anymore you can search for a new one using the [Ubuntu Sources List Generator](https://repogen.simplylinux.ch/).

I would choose "Main - Officially supported software", "Security - Important Security Updates" and "Updates - Recommended Updates".